# C# writing to file in quick succession using FileWatcher OnCreated event

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a net core console which monitors a folder for new files (OnCreated event) and writes to a log file when it sees a change.

The log is written like so:

```
try
{                
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine("c:\logs\", "mylog.txt", message);
}
catch (Exception) {
    //error
}
```

If multiple files (3+) are created at the same time I get the below error:

"The process cannot access the file 'C:\logs\mylog.txt' because it is being used by another process"

I get why this is happening but is there no way of checking the file is in use before carrying on again?

Comment: Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-6.0) to allowing multiple threads for reading or exclusive access for writing.

You should also use AppendAllText instead of WriteAllText if you want to add to the file instead of recreating it each time.

Your code would then look like this

```
public class LogWriter
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim WriteLock = new ();
    
    public void WriteMessage(string message)
    {
        WriteLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:\logs\mylog.txt", message);
        }
        finally
        {
            WriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great in my testing - now going to read up all about it - thanks.